# PHP CURL Response return encoded character

Tags: php, html, curl

Good evening my friend. I have following issue with my curl. I try to view my bank mutation. First thing i have to login. Once the login success and some endpoint hit. I got encoded HTML. I wan to encode but find no way. This is the picture
[image]

And this is the code i use :

```
public function getMutasiRekening($from, $to)
    {
        if( !$this->isLoggedIn ) $this->login( $this->username, $this->password );

        $this->curlSetPost();

        curl_setopt( $this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ib.muamalatbank.com/ib-app-mobile/en/homewelcome' );
        curl_setopt( $this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->_defaultTargets['loginAction'] );
        $this->exec();


        curl_setopt( $this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ib.muamalatbank.com/ib-app-mobile/en/HomeAccountInfo' );
        curl_setopt( $this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://ib.muamalatbank.com/ib-app-mobile/en/homewelcome' );
        $this->exec();


        curl_setopt( $this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ib.muamalatbank.com/ib-app-mobile/en/MI11300a');
        curl_setopt( $this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://ib.muamalatbank.com/ib-app-mobile/en/HomeAccountInfo' );
        $this->exec();

        $params = array(
            'radiogroup=0',
            'hidden=09/01/2019',
            'dfrom-s1=9',
            'dfrom-s2=1',
            'dform-s3=2019',
            'accountSelect=4550004619'
        );
        $params = implode( '&', $params );

        curl_setopt( $this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ib.muamalatbank.com/ib-app-mobile/en/mi11300a.form1' );
        curl_setopt( $this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://ib.muamalatbank.com/ib-app-mobile/en/MI11300a' );

        curl_setopt( $this->curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params );
        $html = $this->exec();

        var_dump("Content of HTML");
        var_dump(html_entity_decode(  iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $html) ));
        exit;

        return $this->getMutasiRekeningTable($html);
    }
```

Comment: You need `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); ` and catch it into a variable. Else it's gonna spill on the screen. See [here](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: We have no idea what data it is your fetching. It almost looks like binary data. If it is encode, we don't know how it's encoded so it would be impossible for us to know how to decode it.